# Internal and external ip

Tags: linux, ssh

How to find the internal IP and external IP of a linux server by connecting to it using Putty?
Secondly, what is the IP address given by the `echo $SSH_CLIENT` command, is it internal or external?

My last question is - Is Back netip and external ip same?

Answer (score 4):

Once you have connected to the server, these commands will get you the information you want (I will assume that this is a simple setup where the server has one network interface and IP configured) :

1. Get the server's internal IP:

   ```
   ip addr show | perl -ne '/inet\s*([\d\.]+).*global/ && do {print "$1\n"}'
   ```

   The `ip addr show` command returns quite a lot of information (run it by itself once to see), I pass its output to a Perl one-liner that looks for an IP address (a stretch of digits and dots: `[\d\.]+`) on a line that contains the words `inet` and `global` and prints the IP found.
2. Get the server's external IP:

   ```
   wget -qO - http://cfajohnson.com/ipaddr.cgi
   ```

---

The `SSH_CLIENT` variable contains the following information:

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT
123.456.78.90 36436 22
------------- ----- --
      |         |   |-----> The server's TCP port
      |         |---------> The client's (your local pc) TCP port
      |-------------------> The client's IP address
```

No idea what you mean by `Back netip`.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, at a command prompt, you can find the internal IP address by typing /sbin/ifconfig (typically look for the device eth0 - the address associated with that is the internal IP address).  As a side note, 127.0.0.1 is always a local address of that PC on a correctly configured IPV4 network.

Assuming you are talking about a typical home network, where the router is performing NAT, you can't tell the systems external IP address directly, you will need to get this reflected off the wider internet.

```
lynx http://www.whatismyip.com
```

will do that for you.

I am unfamiliar with the term "Back netip" - you may want to provide more context, as these are not terms typically used when talking in Linux and Networks.

It appears that $SSH_CLIENT is the "IP address, source port and destination port" that a box you have SSH'd into associates with the connection, ie the computer that connected too it.